# How do I change the field border color to red based on a value in another field?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to compare two fields, and if the value in one field is greater than 3, I'm trying to make the other field required and have a red border to signal the user to input a value.

Here's my existing code, which I got to work to make the other field required - but I'm not sure how to add the border color in. All help is appreciated!

```
var v = this.getField("DISP_CODE_1").value;

if(v > 3){
event.target.required = true;
}
else {
event.target.required = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var v = this.getField("DISP_CODE_1").value;

if(v > 3){
    event.target.required = true;
    event.target.className += " " + classNameWithRedBorder;
}
else {
    event.target.required = false;
}
```

With JQuery, you could use .addClass() and .removeClass() to add/remove the css which would make it easier to act dynamically.